# How to make a localization of d3.js axis?

Tags: d3.js, localization

I know about [that page](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Localization), but how should I use that locale to display a localized months and days on axis? I have dates like so "2014-11-14T00:00:00+03:00" and now I'm just using `new Date()`, not special d3.time.format. If I will make locale.timeFormat, how to implement that to display properly on axis?

I tried one thing. Made a `d3.locale`, made localized format variable with `locale.timeFormat('%b')` and then put it in [tickFormat](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes#tickFormat) function. It's ok, I had localized months. But with no special format labels on axis are more flexible — they will show you years if you have big domain, and days if you have small. Is it possible to make such flexible labels in preferred language?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this doc page : https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting#format_multi

> the default time format used by d3.time.scale is implemented as:

```
var format = d3.time.format.multi([
  [".%L", function(d) { return d.getMilliseconds(); }],
  [":%S", function(d) { return d.getSeconds(); }],
  ["%I:%M", function(d) { return d.getMinutes(); }],
  ["%I %p", function(d) { return d.getHours(); }],
  ["%a %d", function(d) { return d.getDay() && d.getDate() != 1; }],
  ["%b %d", function(d) { return d.getDate() != 1; }],
  ["%B", function(d) { return d.getMonth(); }],
  ["%Y", function() { return true; }]
]);
```

To localize your time scale with the same logic, you can pass the same array to your locale :

```
var localeMultiTimeFormat = yourLocale.timeFormat.multi([
    [".%L", function(d) { return d.getMilliseconds(); }],
    ...
]);
yourScale.tickFormat(localeMultiTimeFormat);
```

Comment: wow, I read that page a lot of times and actually didn't find the answer.